# Objective-c - code after preprocessor

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to view the "source" of my app code after the preprocessor of compiler parse it ?

Answer (score 2):

Menu Build > Preprocess in Xcode.

Comment: I thought that the preprocessor removes all white spaces. So I was expecting the code to looks like this 
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) { NSUInteger myIntVariable = 5;

Everything in one line.

Comment: @ruby_newbie No, the preprocessor doesn’t do that. It essentially applies preprocessor directives (`#include`, `#define`) and substitutions.